# Google spreadsheet, from row to column

Tags: google-sheets

I have many rows on my google spreadsheet witch look like this :
[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Vt8.png)

The first column has the same 4 values, and I wish to have these as "header row," like this :

[IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty0im.png)

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: I have emails & phone numbers. Can't share it online.

Comment: That's fine, you shouldn't share private data, but then please share a synthetic sample of your data.

Comment: I think it's reasonable that you take the time to set up a minimal reproducible example to work on.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
=QUERY({A2:B}, "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
```

[image]

to remove empty cells you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({IF(A2:B="",,A2:B&"×")}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Not working well. Maybe because some cells are empty?

Comment: @PalaghiuMarian can you share a fake sample of your sheet?